# Can you put placeholders in select part of a query using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I plan to use PDO's `prepare()` and `execute()` mechanism to prevent SQL injection attack.

Normally the placeholders in a SQL is in the conditional part.

For example
`select name, age from members where age > ? and gender = 'f';`

However, is it possible to put placeholders in the select part?

`select name, age, ? from members where age > ? and gender = 'f';`

I know I can't put column names there, but can I put constant?  like

`select name, age, 'foo' from members where age > ? and gender ='f';`

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are asking because you tried and got an error message. You should mention that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. PDO can't sanitize column or table names.

If you really *have* to use dynamic table names, the safest way to deal with them is no check whether they actually exist in the table, and inserting them into the query the normal way.

Pseudo-code:

```
$fieldname = make_sure_this_field_really_exists($_GET["fieldname"]);    
$PDO->prepare("select name, age, `$fieldname` from members where age > ? and gender = 'f';" ... );
```