# PDO INSERT simple snippet that plainly doesn't work

Tags: php, insert, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you put placeholders in select part of a query using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301066/can-you-put-placeholders-in-select-part-of-a-query-using-pdo)

I don't like to ask so 'simple' questions, but this code is not working and I cannot figure out why after 1 hour trying ($this->DB is working without problem).

This code doesn't work:

```
$STH = $this->DB->prepare("INSERT INTO chapters (subject_keyword, type, ?) VALUES (?, 'Introduction', ?)");
$STH->execute(array($this->Language, str_replace(' ', '_', $Title), $Introduction));
print_r($STH->ErrorInfo());
```

Nor the expanded form:

```
$t_lang = $this->Language;
$t_title = str_replace(' ', '_', $Title);
$t_intr = $Introduction;
$STH = $this->DB->prepare("INSERT INTO chapters (subject_keyword, type, ?) VALUES (?, 'Introduction', ?)");
$STH->execute(array($t_lang, $t_title, $t_intr));
print_r($STH->ErrorInfo());
```

And the returned error is:

> DDC: 164Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''en') VALUES ('Test_tittle', 'Introduction', '
>   \r\n    This is the introduction t' at line 1 )

That error doesn't indicate much for me, as these few mysql lines seem right except maybe for the \r\n. But I've also tried to do `htmlentities($Introduction)` and few other things with no luck. All the variables here are set and with some not-null value.

Comment: Can you please show the values of the data you are trying to insert ?

Comment: You cannot use placeholders for column names.

Comment: "en", "Test tittle" and "This is the introduction text."

Comment: I was just trying to figure out that @PeeHaa, how can I do it then? With bindParam?

Comment: No you simply can not. Use a whitelist or rethink your design.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos Because it is already answered elsewhere so I don't think I need to pollute the system even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$t_lang = $this->Language;
if (!in_array($t_lang, array('en', 'jp', ... Your other languages ...))) {
    throw new Exception(... Error message ...);
}
$t_title = str_replace(' ', '_', $Title);
$t_intr = $Introduction;
$STH = $this->DB->prepare("INSERT INTO chapters (subject_keyword, type, " . $t_lang . ") VALUES (?, 'Introduction', ?)");
$STH->execute(array($t_title, $t_intr));
print_r($STH->ErrorInfo());
```

Comment: Isn't this just vulnerable to injection?

Comment: It depends where your $t_lang comes from. Also I edited my answer.

Comment: Very true, but it comes from a relatively long way and I read somewhere that I should make it injection-safe before using it in database, so I better clean it. Besides, I'm just using this.
After your edit, my code looks almost the same (;